# How can I re-use same class definitions in both Node.JS and client-side JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am building a chess-based web application using Node.JS. I want to create some base class of chess piece and inherit each piece from it. How can I do the class implementation only once, and then re-use same .js file in both client and server part? And also, how can I encode object of my class from server and send it to client?

Comment: Probably you are looking for `http://browserify.org/` project

Comment: The other alternative is you can test which root element is available then expose the implementation as required `var root = (typeof window == "undefined") ? module : window; root.myImpl = function(){}`  For serialization usually stripping all methods is required (or inheriting them from a prototype so they're not enumerable) then you can simply `JSON.stringify` your object and send it via AJAX/websocket then implement a constructor/update method as required. It's best to be aware that maintaining state can sometimes be tricky with more complex implementations.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski good point, I'll take a look

Answer (score 0):

One ***dependency free*** approach is to check if `module` exists and, if so - you are in a NodeJS (*CommonJS*) environment so you'll need to export your `function`/`class`/`variable` to use it. e.g.

```
class Foo {
   // class defintion goes here
}
if (module) module.exports = Foo;
```

Comment: What about class inheritance? I think base class and inherited class should be the different modules in Node.JS, am I wrong?

Comment: They don't have to be in different modules. But if you want to have them in different modules you could extend the above example to require the other module `if (module) ...`.